# regular expression - replacement for $ and ^

Tags: regex

I have a system that uses regular expressions to validate input, but I can't use the `$` or `^` characters.

Is there another way to get the affect that they give?

For example I have the text

```
This is New-York city
```

the regular expression `[A-z]+` will find this valid, although I didn't specify the hyphen character in the regular expression and `^[A-z]+$` will find this sentence not valid

Comment: **What** system ? It looks like the core of the problem...

Comment: Why can't you use $ and ^?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it won't match the whole string because `[A-z]+` matches one or more characters in the range `A-z`, but `-`, space wasn't falls within this range so if you use the anchors `^`, `$` it won't match the whole string.

If you add `-`, space into the character class then it should work.

```
^[A-z\s-]+$
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/vF9jV6/5)

Instead of `^`, you could use `\A` and for end `$`, use `\Z`

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/vF9jV6/6)

Answer (score 1):

Yes: Use `\A` and `\Z`, which mean "start" and "end" of input:

```
\A[a-zA-Z ]+\Z
```

This matches sentences comprised of letters and spaces only.

I fixed your character class to what I think you intended.

FYI ^ and $ mean start/end of *line*.